# using alias instead of IP in scp

Tags: shell, unix

I have a desktop in the office that I often need to access from home and use scp to copy files. Currently I am doing it like this

```
scp username@x.x.x.x  ...
```

I want a mechanism that I dont have to type the IP address each time I want to scp something. I was trying to do it by creating an alias, but it doesn't seem to work.
Can I give my desktop machine a name so that instead of typing the ip address I can use the name of the machine instead ?

Comment: You say you tried to create an alias. Can you show the corresponding part of your ssh config file?

Answer (score 7):

One way to deal with this is to create an entry in your ssh configuration. This can be done on a system wide basis or, if you don't have root access on this box, just for your user.

The per user configuration file is `~/.ssh/config` and uses the following format

```
host my_desktop
    hostname 11.22.33.44
```

This method is also nice because you can specify other options like the user name. To find out more about the options available try `man ssh_config`.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a `HOSTS` file on your system that's designed to do exactly that.  On my Linux system, it's located at `/etc/hosts`.  If you add a line that looks like this:

```
11.22.33.44   my_desktop
```

then all accesses to the name `my_desktop` will be mapped to the IP address listed.  This change only affects the machine whose `HOSTS` file was modified, though.  If you want to make it so that *anybody* can access an IP using a specific name, then you're looking at something a little more difficult (this is the general problem that DNS servers were designed to resolve).

Comment: That mechanism is available on most systems, the wikipedia page shows where they are all hidden http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Answer (score 2):

Use a environment variable to hold your IP and username - then use the variable in the scp command.

```
user@crunchbang:~$ export mypc='myuser@x.x.x.x'

user@crunchbang:~$ scp $mypc: ......
```